# java file reading-writing, fails at encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, file-encodings

I've got an issue where java reads my file, which in notepad++ it shows 
UCS-2 LE BOM encoding, and I'm trying to change tabs inside it to commas. After conversion every character has a NUL behind it, and at the beggining of the file there are "��" characters. Basically , the encoding is failing.
Currenctly I'm using this code to convert the file from a tabbed csv to a comma seperated csv.

```
            Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);
            Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
            content = content.replaceAll("\t", ",");
            Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
```

What may be failing here?
And before you comment - I can't remake the program to work with tab seperated files.

Comment: This is unclear. UCS2 is an encoding where every character takes up 2 bytes in the file, as opposed to, say, UTF-8 in which multi-byte sequences are introduced with specific prefix characters.  For standard ASCII, there _should_ be a null byte for every character.  Are you sure the input is UCS2?  You seem to be surprised by the 2-bytes per character appearance.  You will need to explain more clearly what the issue is.

Comment: I would assume its UTF-16 LE encoding, or two bytes per character.

Comment: @JimGarrison whn I'm trying to parse the file and convert it ,but it breaks the content. I've changed the type to utf-16 for the input file, and it's ok now. Is there a way to auto-detect the encoding of the file? because I'm trying to rewrite the file, if the parser would to run again with the same file as input - it's encoding wouldn't be utf-16 after the first conversion, and it will break the contents of the file...